# How can I make changes reflect on vite js

Tags: vite

I have a vite project install already on a live server , but whenever I make changes to the code base or I edit a text , changes don’t reflect even when I refresh the browser… so I’m asking if there’s any command to run on my terminal to make changes reflect.

i only tried refreshing my browser but it didn’t work , I’m not really familiar with vite js .

Comment: Are you running your live preview with `npm run dev`? Could you show what code you're altering? I recommend watching a short youtube video tutorial such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=731woPHHVNU) to get started.

Comment: I made changes to some files in the resource folder, edited some writeup , but it’s not reflecting on my browser still shows the same old text and it’s faustrating